# Where in norse literature was 'Galdrakinn' used as a nickname, as recorded by Cleasby?

Tags: scandinavian-languages

The ONP [page for Galdrahríð](https://onp.ku.dk/onp/onp.php?o25707) has definitions from Cleasby & Zoega, and lists all the words containing the headword *Galdra*, including this one.

> galdra-kinn, f. a ‘spell-cheek,’ a nickname, Eb.

Other entries have a citation that can be clicked, but this one, *Eb.* can not be. What is it referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer moments after writing the question, but I thought I'd add a self-answer in case this trip anybody else up in the future (like me, when I forget how this works).

You can search the 'Works' tab for abbreviated references, like *Eb.*

[image: Search results for Eb.]

Here *Eb.* refers to the *Eyrbyggja saga*.